# Opening a program under a different user account

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to run a program under a different user account and am unable to find anything related. I have the passwords for each user, Administrator access and if needed I can call the code from a service.

**Example:** User1 and User2 are logged into their Windows account on the same machine. From User1, I need to open notepad.exe under User2. The program should behave as if it was launched from User2 account. It should be under Users2's desktop if I use switch user.

I know I can log in and run the program from that account, but that's not the solution I'm looking to use. Also, runas user is not the same as it will open under the current user desktop nor will impersonation work for the same reason.

Any help/suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use WTSQueryUserToken from a service.  But since you have the passwords (and admin rights) you could use LogonUser, SetTokenInformation (to set the session) and CreateProcessAsUser instead.  (You'd also need to use some of the WTS functions to identify the session you want to launch the process in.)